# Macbook pro 13" mid-2012 not turning on, no battery leds (battery ok)

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery, power, logicboard

My MacBook pro 13" 2012 won't boot up. The battery leds on the outside aren't indicating anything either and the charger won't show bright green or amber led.

Is my logic board the cause?

Things I've tried:

- Tried a SMC reset
- A different, working battery
- A different, working charger
- Using the MacBook without the battery connected to see if it would start up
- Trying to connect the power pads on the logic board

Attached a few photos of the board and connectors.

[image: entire board][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRyD3.jpg)
[image: battery connector][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS8Oe.jpg)
[image: fan and connectors][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smK4V.jpg)
[image: screen connector and magsafe][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36KTo.jpg)
[image: keyboard connector][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9jR8.jpg)

Comment: when you tried different "working" battery, how did you know it was in working condition/fully charged. and what happened.

Comment: I took it out of a running MacBook Pro that was running of battery power.

Comment: lets go back to how it stopped working in first place. Did you shut it down or id it do it by it self.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I got it like this. It was a free pickup.

Comment: I see, someone gave up on it. Use Digital Volt meter and see if you can detect any power on the logic board.

Comment: I will need to source a meter then, where would I measure? Can you give a few sample points?

Comment: and  you a sure it is not dead display

Comment: No start-up sounds, no leds, no keyboard lights. Display may be dead as well, but I think that is a later concern.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how many other people will encounter this, but the previous owner of this MacBook made an error while replacing either the battery status led part, or the battery itself.

When I once again tried to re-seat the battery, I saw that the cable to the led indicator was damaged. Apparently it had shifted somehow and got damaged by the outside screw of the battery. After I disconnected the cable (and eventually snipped off the damaged part of the indicator to prevent it hanging loose), the MacBook booted and is running and charging it's battery just  fine. So, if the cable in the picture is damaged and shortcircuits to the case, your Mac may not boot or do anything at all.

[image: last bit of the led indicator cable]

Comment: get a digital multimeter anyway, it could have helped you solve this problem faster.

Comment: Definitely. This was just an accidental discovery.